# In CUDA why can't I allocate 2d shared memory dynamically?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

The following works fine;

```
__extern__ float dyanimicSh1D[];
```

But the following does not work:

```
__extern__ float dyanimicSh2D[][];
```

I want to understand why it is so?

Comment: That isn't syntactically valid in C++. Why do you expect it would work in CUDA?

Comment: But in C  I can do:.    int two_d[10][20];

Comment: That isn't the same thing

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it because the compiler needs the **width** information for the array  to generate code that does proper indexing.

If you allocate shared memory in a static fashion like this:

```
__shared__ float sarr[24][12];
```

Then not only are you telling how much memory to allocate/provide, you are also giving the *width* of the array (12 in this example).  This is important, because a static 2D array of this type is not treated under the hood as an array of pointers, but instead it is a flat allocation, with indexing created by the compiler, at compile-time.

so that later when you do something like this:

```
float val = sarr[y][x];
```

the compiler will take the `sarr` pointer, and do pointer arithmetic to add x + (y*12) to it, before dereferencing that pointer to retrieve the value.  The 12 in that calculation is discovered at compile-time and used by the compiler in generating the code to do the indexing.

Doing something like this:

```
extern __shared__ float sarr[][];
```

doesn't supply the array width information to the compiler, so it cannot generate the indexing needed at compile time, and is not allowed.

By the way, this works:

```
extern __shared__ float sarr[][12];
```

Here is an example:

```
$ cat t46.cu
#include <cstdio>
__global__ void k(int x, int y){

  extern __shared__ float sarr[][12];
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i ++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
      sarr[i][j] = i * 256 + j;
  float val = sarr[y][x];
  printf("%f\n", val);
}

int main(){

  k<<<1,1,128*12>>>(3,2);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t46 t46.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t46
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
515.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```